# How avoid goto in error processing

Tags: c++, error-handling, goto

I know how horrible and hard to read programs with `goto`s are, and I'd like to avoid them at all costs, as everyone else.

*However*, I encountered a situation where I had a hard time avoiding them while having an elegant program. It is with error processing. I do a lot of steps, and if there is an error in any of the step, the program should display an error message, free some memory and return `false`. If everything works, it should return `true`.

The original program is like that :

```
bool init_routine()
{
     int errcode;   // Error code
     errcode = do_someting();
     if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
     {
         free_some_memory();
         std::cerr << "Something went wrong in initialization.";
         return false;
     }
     errcode = do_something_else();
     if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
     {
         free_some_more_memory();   // Was allocated in the do_something function
         free_some_memory();
         std::cerr << "Something went wrong in initialization.";
         return false;
     }
     /* The same pattern repeats quite a few times... */
     return true;   // Everything was ok
}
```

This is ugly, because some code is copy-pasted over and over, which is bad practice. I could use a function, but then the function cannot `return false` from the callee, because C++ lacks what I'd call a *double return instruction*.

Another way to do it, is to use nested `if` :

```
bool init_routine()
{
     int errcode;   // Error code
     errcode = do_someting();
     if(errcode == RETURN_SUCCESS)
     {
         errcode = do_something_else();
         if(errcode == RETURN_SUCCESS)
         {
             /* The same pattern repeats quite a few times */
             if()
             {
                if()
                {
                      if()
                      {
                         return true;
                      }
                }
             }
         }
         free_some_more_memory();
     }
     free_some_memory();
     std::cerr << "Something went wrong in initialization.";
     return false;
}
```

This avoids any repetition and is compact. However, as the number of nested `if` grows quickly, the indentation gets in the way. Moreover, all those `if` hides the simple control flow of the program which just sequentially executes instructions and exits on errors, and makes the reader believe there is a lot of complicated conditions to follow.

Another way, which is in my opinion more natural, is :

```
bool init_routine()
{
     int errcode;   // Error code
     errcode = do_someting();
     if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
     {
         goto err1;
     }
     errcode = do_something_else();
     if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
     {
         goto err2;
     }
     /* The same pattern repeats quite a few times... */
     return true;   // Everything was ok

err2:
     free_some_more_memory();
err1:
     free_some_memory();
     std::cerr << "Something went wrong in initialization";
     return false;
}
```

There is no repetition, the only problem is that the evil `goto` is used. My question is :

**Is there a way to not use `goto`, while not using repetition, not using exceptions, and not having insane indentation ?**

EDIT : Just to make it clear, I can't use exceptions because the routines I call are from an external library written in C, and I call them from my C++ code. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: No. Just use exceptions.

Comment: Make the code more RAII and the `free...()`s will go away.

Comment: One Approach is to used scoped_ptr and scoped objects that will be automatically "cleaned" when you leave the function instead of using manual memory management ( free_some_more_memory ).

See boost : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm

Or the C++11 one http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: Use exceptions and wrap your C++ functions in another C++ function which catches any exceptions and then converts them to your other error type.

Comment: You say that you can't use exceptions because your (C++?) code calls C code, but there is no reason not to convert that C library's return codes to exception. Actually, writing a thin wrapper that defines its own exception type, converts error codes to them and provides RAII wrappers for resources is written quickly and helps removing tedious C-style error handling from the application logic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, I figured that out already (as I've said in the comments parts of your answer). That's definitely the most elegant way to solve the problem, and it feels C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. While I don't use `goto` there are respected programmers who do use `forward-gotos` in cases like this. Anyway, there is an alternative solution: create a one-shot loop.
2. I also agree with the other guys, use RAII if possible. However in certain situations (e.g. legacy *do_something()*) you can do some 'manual-RAII' with boolean flags.

So your code can be refactored like this:

```
bool init_routine()
{
    int errcode;   // Error code
    bool need_free_some_memory = false;
    bool need_free_some_more_memory = false;

    do { //not a loop, just scope for break

        need_free_some_memory = true;
        errcode = do_something();

        if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
            break;

        need_free_some_more_memory = true;
        errcode = do_something_else();
        if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
            break;

    } while(0);

    if(need_free_some_more_memory)
        free_some_more_memory();   // Was allocated in the do_something function
    if(need_free_some_memory)
        free_some_memory();

    if(errcode != RETURN_SUCCESS)
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong in initialization.";

    return errcode == RETURN_SUCCESS;   // Everything was ok
}
```

Comment: Is this not a goto by another name?

Comment: Well, I guess the loop-break relates to the goto is like the global variable relates to the singleton. Essentially the same but maybe expresses the intention better (leave-this-block vs go-somewhere)

Comment: Even if you have legacy C code, `std::shared_ptr` still works. E.g. `shared_ptr<void> memory(malloc(1024), free);`.

Comment: I know this technique as "do once", because its first line is typically written `do { // once`.

Answer (score 2):

Use standard collections, or smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` if you absolutely have to explicitly allocate. They do the deallocation automatically. That's it.

More generally, use objects with destructors that clean up (that's what standard collections and smart pointers do). That's known as RAII, *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization*. Google that to learn more, and look it up in the index of your text book.

By the way, it's not a good idea to mix output into a general function. What if you want to use that code in a GUI program?

Answer (score 1):

If you manage allocated resources using objects representing ownership (using e.g. smart pointers or similar things), these problems just don't occur:

```
resource r;
if (int e = alloc_resource(&r))
    return e;
```

The destructor of `r` will take care of releasing the resource on scope exit.

Using errorcodes instead of exceptions is completely stupid though, because they take up the returnvalue spot, carry only a limited amound of information and you can forget to check them. Use exceptions.

Comment: This might be completely stupid but I'm not the one that writes this part of the code :) It's a library that is written in C, and I call it from my C++ code (it's my fault from not mentioning this). Otherwise, yes I agree completely with what you said.

Comment: However, it's true I could do my C++ wrap-up that just call the library functions and throw an exception whether they return an error code.

Answer (score 1):

Without asking why you try to avoid exceptions:

There are a few ways to do error handling. First there are the C-Style ways. Return an `integer` or `bool` which indicates failure (instead of `void`) or return an error code over an `integer` (in C often the global variable `errno` is used for this). And the ugly `goto`.

The more C++-Style ways:

If your function returns objects or values you could define *invalid* objects (e.g. an image with `width = height = 0`).

The lack of the «double return» in c++ you mentioned is not present in c++11. You could do something like this: `return std::make_pair(obj,true)`.

If you need to handle ressources in error cases I give you the following advice: Don't do it. Use **RAII** instead. It saves you a lot of efford and is save.

Comment: Oh, by double return I meant return directly from two levels of calls, not return two values simultaneously. I did that often when I coded in assembly, but that's another thing.

Comment: "Invalid objects" are specifically not C++ style. There's a reason why the C++ standard goes into extra detail explaining how exceptions work in constructors: it's because they especially are supposed to throw on errors.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, that is right. But the question asked for solution without throwing. It always depends on how the odds of the error are. If it is more likely you sometimes don't want to throw and catch but only wait until you get valid data. If you don't expect it to fail you should definitely use exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`goto` is generally banned because this often results in a rats-nest of `if-then-goto` statements that have no structure. Loops and function calls are much better ways of doing this.

Having said that when it comes to breaking out of deeply nested loops or for error handling `goto`s are an appropriate way of doing things. The `goto` cleanup pattern is used extensively in the linux kernel for error handling. So for C style programming what you doing is perfectly acceptable.

However in C++ there are often better options. RAII and smart pointers are a good first prize. And exceptions should cover the rest of the need for `goto` although embedded systems often have exceptions disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is using unique_ptr or similar. If that is too inconvinient for you and you are using c++0x or later, you can use finally lambdas:

```
T* resource = some_legacy_c_function();
if(!resource) return false; //or throw, or whatever
FINALLY([&](){
    cleanup(resource);
});
do_stuff_with(resource);
return;//cleanup is called automatically here :)
```

With the finally macro defined as follows (put this somewhere in your header):

```
template<typename F>
class _Finally
{
private:
    F _f;

public:
    inline _Finally(const F& f) :
        _f(f)
    {
    }

    inline ~_Finally(){
        _f();
    };
};

template<typename F>
inline _Finally<F> Finally(const F& f)
{
    return _Finally<F>(f);
}

#define FINALLY auto __finally_##__LINE__ = Finally
```

Comment: `__`  and `_F` are reserved for compiler internal use. `_f` isn't, but since that's the only member of the class you can safely name it `f`. It's not like other code can define `Finally::f` later on.

Comment: @MSalters I am aware that the naming may be against the specs, but these things will show up in code completion and if it starts with _ or __ that tells the user that he probably should not use that directly. Also, naming collisions are rather unlikely.

Comment: That's why you put these things in a different `namespace`; that should keep them away from code completion.

Comment: Why is `_Finally` copy-constructible? Copying it would cause multiple calls to the cleanup function, AFAICT. BTW, you don't need a semicolon after function definitions like the dtor.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Intended use is using the macro only and not touch the variable or class directly. If the user does not touch the instance, it won't be copied. But since people seem to dislike the coding style rather than the functionality, I'll make this post community wiki, so you can edit it until the coding style is to your likings :)

Comment: This is not about style, @Zotta, you have a function creating these objects. Returning them from a function can copy them, as does storing them outside of a function. Your code only works because the compiler performs RVO. See this http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758 for instructions how to do it right.